# I want new array from existing array has one of old array key and value

Tags: php, arrays

$main_array = array( [
"XS",
"S",
"M",
"L",
"XL"
],
[
"12",
"34",
"56"
],
[
"Series 6/SE-44 MM",
"Series 7-45 MM"
]

);

Want result as below:

$result = array(
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xs",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xs",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xs",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xs",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xs",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xs",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "s",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "s",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "s",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "s",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "s",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "s",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "m",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "m",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "m",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "m",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "m",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "m",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "l",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "l",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "l",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "l",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "l",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "l",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xl",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xl",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xl",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "44-mm",
"test"=> "56"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xl",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "12"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xl",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "34"
),
array(
"pa_clothes"=> "xl",
"pa_apple_watch"=> "45-mm",
"test"=> "56"
)
);

Comment: so you want to remove "Series 6/SE-" text on pa_apple_watch key?

Comment: no, we keep all array value

Comment: Okay so you need the combination of each value from each array. right?

Comment: Ok, Let me combine all result array and sent you.

Comment: I have update result on my question already. could you please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you required

```
$array1 = [
    "XS",
    "S",
    "M",
    "L",
    "XL"
];
$array2 = [
    "12",
    "34",
    "56"
];
$array3 = [
    "Series 6/SE-44 MM",
    "Series 7-45 MM"
];

$myArray = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $j++) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($array3); $k++) {
            $myArray[] = [
                'pa_clothes' => $array1[$i],
                'test' => $array2[$j],
                'pa_apple_watch' => $array3[$k]
            ];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: how we can apply with dynamic array.

Comment: this is for dynamic array as well as it just iterating with the array size only. so even you have any number of elements in any array, it would work

Comment: Could you update your answer again please, I have update the question according to my real issue

Answer (score 0):

assume that each `$array1 $array2 $array3` count are same.

```
$newArray = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){
    $newArray[] = [
         'pa_clothes' => $array1[$i],
         'test' => $array2[$i],
         'pa_apple_watch' => $array3[$i],
    ];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```